# UI not updated Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, user-interface, flutter-web, setstate

I have a Table reading data from Firestore, using StreamBuilder. I have a button Add Element below the table that when clicked opens a pop-up form. After the user fills the form and clicks the button, data is stored in Firestore, the Dialog form is closed and the user is redirected to the table. When I use only text form fields in my form, the table is updated with the new data that the user just pushed in Firestore. The problem started to occurs when I added an Upload Picture Form, which uploads the picture in Firebase Storage and pushes the download URL as a field inside the other information of the form. I fill the form and the Table doesn't update. The project is in Flutter Web so I am using image_picker_web for the upload process and the Image file is MediaInfo type. As I said it started to happen only when I added the upload picture form along with other TextFormFields.

```
                   // Upload Picture Field
                   InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        final MediaInfo _image =
                            await ImagePickerWeb.getImageInfo;
                        setState(() {
                          image = _image;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: Center(
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      CupertinoIcons.cloud_upload,
                                      color: Colors.grey[600],
                                    ),
                                    const SizedBox(
                                      width: 5,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      'Upload the invoice picture',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey[600],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                      ),
                    ),
                      //Create Invoice Button
                      MaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                        Invoice invoice = Invoice(
                              _controllerInvoiceNumber.text,
                              _controllerLocation.text,
                              invoiceDate,
                              _controllerAmount.text,
                            );

                            Database().addNewInvoice(
                              invoice,
                              _userId!,
                              image!,
                            );

                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const HomePage(),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          'Create',
                        ),
                      ),

         //Table 
         StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Invoices')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }

              return Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    child: PlutoGrid(
                      columns: editableColumns,
                      rows: _createRows(snapshot.data),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Center(
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        child: const Text(
                          'Add Invoice',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return const AddInvoiceForm();
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Instead of describing your code, and the flow through it, please edit your question to *include* the [minimal code that any of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).